# Как установить filterrific на ruby on rails v. 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

filterrific обновился и теперь не работает на rails 4 версии, как исправить этот конфликт ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

укажите в Gemfile версию [совместимую с Rails 4.x](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific#compatibility)

```
gem 'filterrific', '~> 4.0'
```